# ImageView invisible doesn't get visible after setVisibility()

Tags: android, imageview, visibility, findviewbyid

I load in `onCreate()` and ImageView by `findViewById()`. The ImageView is set as INVISIBLE from XML and it should become visible in `onStart()` by calling `mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

The strange thing is that the visibility is not changed whereas if I set GONE from XML the visibility is actually changed.

Is there something that I'm missing?

EDIT:

The code:

```
private class MyClass extends Activity {
...
private ImageView mImage;
...


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewCompass);
......
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

and from XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeBus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCompass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/mwImage"
        android:visibility="invisible" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I have just posted it...btw it is very standard code....

Comment: I tried to duplicate your code and with both invisible and gone the image appeared. Did you try cleaning and building your code, maybe there is just something else getting in the way.

Comment: I tried to build the project and to delete the R class...nothing changes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but I realized my self that I was not clear enough. I'm using an OpenGL SurfaceView and I would not have believed it could be annoying to other Views.. It seems that the `setVisibility()` method has some problems starting from `View.INVISIBLE` when working on a layer above a SurfaceView..

Here I found the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12655713/2402640

Answer (score 0):

First thing is why are you declaring your activity class as private class. Only public, abstract & final are permitted. Secondly I copied and pasted the exact code provided by you and created a new android application project and it works fine. 
Can you please post the full .xml file.

Comment: It was a mistake. the class is public ofc :) full xml posted

Comment: Why are you re declaring relativelayout width and height ? Remove it and then try again.

Comment: because there was another layout as parent. removing width and height is the same.

Comment: Well then something is wrong with the other stuff. To verify that try creating a new Android Application project and just copy and paste the above code you have provided and run it. The above code works fine on my end.