# How to hide a Relative layout visiblity after completion of video in Tab?

Tags: android, xml, video, android-relativelayout

I have designed code where after the completion of the video the visibility of the `RelativeLayout` where the video view is placed should become `GONE`.

```
vid.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        rel_withvideo_food.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mp.stop();
    }
});
```

This code is working on Samsung Galaxy S2 but not on Tab. When I play another video, the `RelativeLayout` visibility is not getting `GONE`.The next video plays on the backside of the previous video.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236336/setvisibilityview-visible-doesnt-always-work-ideas) help?

Comment: what? Marius I am not getting Your point.

Comment: Your code had syntax issues, even after somebody previously fixed some of the formatting. The parentheses and braces were unbalanced. I tried to clean it up. Please make sure that you post code that could be built.

Answer (score 0):

`SurfaceView` is the sole culprit (of course, this also applies to `GLSurfaceView`, `RSSurfaceView` and `VideoView`, all of which inherits from `SurfaceView`). It exposes lots of weird behaviours when dealing with other views on top of it. Playing with `View.setVisibility()` is one of those issues. Clearly, `SurfaceView` has not been designed to be used with other views (even though the official doc says it ought to be) but as a standalone view for videos, games or OpenGL stuffs.

For the visibility issue, I've found that using `View.GONE` instead of `View.INVISIBLE` resolve it. If you don't want to use `View.GONE`, try changing the focus for example (and back to the one that had focus before), or changing other states. The goal is to wake up the underlying UI system somehow.

In short: when something weird happens with your views and you have a `SurfaceView` (or subclass) somewhere, try replacing it with something else so you don't lose hours searching what you're doing wrong when you're doing it right (and no false beliefs). This way, you know `SurfaceView` is to blame and you can hack around it with beautiful comments to piss on it without qualms.

As answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236336/setvisibilityview-visible-doesnt-always-work-ideas)

**EDIT:**

Get a copy of `LayoutParams` for later use:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rllp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) vid
            .getLayoutParams();
```

Remove VideoView completely

```
((ViewGroup) vid.getParent()).removeView(vid);
```

Recreate `VideoView` with same `LayoutParams` when needed.

```
vid = new VideoView(someContext);
vid.setLayoutParams(rllp);
```

Comment: So what can I do for this.?

Comment: Get a copy of `LayoutParams` and remove the VideoView completely, then add it again when needed.